# Wordpress (behind HAProxy and Jetty), not multisite, in sub folder - and /en/wp-admin/ keeps redirecting to /wp-admin/

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, directory, installation, wp-config

I am using an unusual setup to host 3 Wordpress installations on CentOS 8 Linux.

In front I have HAProxy (to offload TLS), then I have [Jetty configured for FastCGI](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-fastcgi) and php-fpm and finally Wordpress.

I am using the Wordpress around a word game written in Pixi.js.

For several years now I have been using 3 different IP-addresses and 3 different domain names for the 3 language versions of my game: en, de, ru.

However my word game is not successful, so I have decided to give up the additional domain names and IP addresses and just use folders to serve my game:

- wordsbyfarber.com/en
- wordsbyfarber.com/de
- wordsbyfarber.com/ru

This has worked well, I am not using multisite and I have set

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://wordsbyfarber.com/en');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://wordsbyfarber.com/en');
```

in en/wp-config.php (same for de and ru) and also in the dashboard:

[image: dashboard]

And already you can see my problem in the above screenshot:

While the user-facing websites work ok, the admin dashboard at `/en/wp-admin/` immediately redirects to `/wp-admin` which is not ok, since I am not using multisite.

I have tried to solve the problem myself and searched a lot in the docs etc.

Also I wondered, who is doing the redirect, is it JS or PHP?

It seems to me that this is done by the PHP code of Wordpress, which for some reason sends a new `Location` header:

[image: wget]

As you can see in the above screenshot, when using `wget` - for some reason Wordpress would remove `/en` string from `/en/wp-admin` path and redirect to the new location.

Why is it doing so and how to stop it?

I have tried to search in Wordpress source code with:

```
find ./en/ -iname \*.php| xargs grep -riw redirect_to
```

but wasn't able to find the reason yet.

**UPDATE:** I do not have any .htaccess file, because I am using [Jetty configured for FastCGI](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-fastcgi) with the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">

    <New id="root" class="java.lang.String">
        <Arg>/var/www/html/wordsbyfarber.com/en</Arg>
    </New>

    <Set name="contextPath">/en</Set>
    <Set name="resourceBase"><Ref refid="root" /></Set>

    <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="string">
                <Item>index.php</Item>
                <Item>index.html</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>

    <Call name="addFilter">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.fcgi.server.proxy.TryFilesFilter</Arg>
        <Arg>/*</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <Call name="of" class="java.util.EnumSet">
                <Arg><Get name="REQUEST" class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" /></Arg>
            </Call>
        </Arg>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>files</Arg>
            <Arg>$path /index.php?p=$path</Arg>
        </Call>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addServlet">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                <Arg>default</Arg>
                <Arg>
                    <Call name="forName" class="java.lang.Class">
                        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</Arg>
                    </Call>
                </Arg>
                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                    <Arg>dirAllowed</Arg>
                    <Arg>false</Arg>
                </Call>
                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                    <Arg>gzip</Arg>
                    <Arg>true</Arg>
                </Call>
            </New>
        </Arg>
        <Arg>/</Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addServlet">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.fcgi.server.proxy.FastCGIProxyServlet</Arg>
        <Arg>*.php</Arg>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>proxyTo</Arg>
            <Arg>http://localhost:9000</Arg>
        </Call>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>prefix</Arg>
            <Arg>/</Arg>
        </Call>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>scriptRoot</Arg>
            <Arg><Ref refid="root" /></Arg>
        </Call>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>scriptPattern</Arg>
            <Arg>(.+?\\.php)</Arg>
        </Call>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Have you used a database migration tool? In addition to the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL options, WP tends to store URLs in serialized arrays throughout the database. Since they're serialized, you want to do more than a simple search and replace, so there are various plugins and WP-CLI commands to do this safely.

Comment: I have not used the migration tool, do you happen to know in which SQL table the URLs are stored?

Comment: They're stored in multiple tables. Look for a database migration plugin or service which will guide you through the steps needed to update them all safely (after you've taken a backup).

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have PHPMyAdmin or Adminer or a similar tool installed in your web server? You could easily run a search & replace. I'd recommend running a search and see if all the matching records make sense. Then, run a search & replace.
As @WebElaine mentioned, WP tends to store the URLs in several places, including some plugins, so it is not always a straight answer.

Answer (score 0):

These URLs are stored in `[prefix]_options` (generally wp_options) table.
But as soon as you define `WP_HOME` and `SITE_URL` in config file, these options automatically get disabled in admin.

To me this issue doesn't seems to be wordpress related, rather it appears to be something in your jetty config for fastcgi.

Comment: Shouldn't the tryfilesfilter contain the subdirectory path too ?

Comment: Mohammad, yes I have tried many values there - but could not find a working combination

Comment: in nginx it's like 
`location /wordpress {   try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;    }`
For sub directories. 
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can try "force" WordPress to use your manually defined site URL. Add this code to your `wp-config.php`. This method is not the best fix but your case is like an emergency :D

```php
define('WP_HOME', 'https://yourwebsite.com/en');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://yourwebsite.com/en');
```

According to WordPress ["Changing The Site URL"](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) page

> This is not necessarily the best fix, it’s just hard-coding the values into the site itself. You won’t be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.

Comment: I already have these 2 lines in my 3 wp-config.php files